# Validate IP Address (host) exists prior to connecting (ping)

Tags: c++, tcp, winsock

I have a problem where I need to determine if the host exists prior to connecting to it. This host does not work with the function `gethostbyaddr()` because it is not PC-based and does not return host information. It is IP-based only. Whenever I try to call `gethostbyaddr()` on the IP address, WinSock returns **11004** (WSANODATA).

Is there a similar function (besides `ping`) to determine if an IP is valid before trying to connect?

Comment: Are you trying to determine whether the IP address is in a valid format, or if there is a device somewhere in the internet configured with that address?

Comment: @0A0D Could you elaborate on why you'd like to check the existence of the IP (whatever that means) instead of simply trying to connect?

Comment: @Al: I can already do `inet_addr` but that just checks whether the IP is formatted correctly, but does not tell you if the host is connected to the network or not.

Comment: @aix: Because I have an issue where I need to check every 2.5 seconds if the IP is up. This eats up local ports in Windows XP. By default in XP, you are only allowed 5000 ephemeral ports with a closing timeout of 300 seconds until they are recycled. If the program is left running for an extended period of time, it will lead to a WSAENOBUFS problem.

Comment: On the modern internet many IP addresses are not directly assigned to individual hosts, so it is not necessarily meaningful to check if a host exists with that address. The only certain way is to experimentally connect to the desired port, so see if you get a response. Any other check might be handled by some other system for any number of good reasons. For example a major web hosting provider might route connection on port 80 through to a set of load balancers which accept a connection, where as connections on other ports might be routed elsewhere by a packet filter.

Comment: @Al: This is a local network so I am not going through any routers or fancy network configuration. All on the same subnet.

Comment: To clarify: which machine is embedded, and which is running Winsock? I can't really tell from your description.

Comment: @Roger: PC is running WinSock, ADAM6060 is embedded.

Comment: @0A0D: and you want the embedded device to ping the PC, or vice-versa?

Comment: @Roger: PC ping embedded device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the built-in Windows API for PING. I changed the `gethostbyname()` to `inet_addr`.

shown here: [ICMP.DLL Method](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/examples/dllping.html)

**dllping.cpp**

```
// Borland C++ 5.0: bcc32.cpp ping.cpp
// Visual C++ 5.0:  cl ping.cpp wsock32.lib
//
// This sample program is hereby placed in the public domain.

#include <iostream.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include "icmpdefs.h"

int doit(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Check for correct command-line args
    if (argc < 2) {
        cerr << "usage: ping <host>" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Load the ICMP.DLL
    HINSTANCE hIcmp = LoadLibrary("ICMP.DLL");
    if (hIcmp == 0) {
        cerr << "Unable to locate ICMP.DLL!" << endl;
        return 2;
    }

    // Look up an IP address for the given host name
    struct hostent* phe;
    if ((phe = gethostbyname(argv[1])) == 0) {
        cerr << "Could not find IP address for " << argv[1] << endl;
        return 3;
    }

    // Get handles to the functions inside ICMP.DLL that we'll need
    typedef HANDLE (WINAPI* pfnHV)(VOID);
    typedef BOOL (WINAPI* pfnBH)(HANDLE);
    typedef DWORD (WINAPI* pfnDHDPWPipPDD)(HANDLE, DWORD, LPVOID, WORD,
            PIP_OPTION_INFORMATION, LPVOID, DWORD, DWORD); // evil, no?
    pfnHV pIcmpCreateFile;
    pfnBH pIcmpCloseHandle;
    pfnDHDPWPipPDD pIcmpSendEcho;
    pIcmpCreateFile = (pfnHV)GetProcAddress(hIcmp,
            "IcmpCreateFile");
    pIcmpCloseHandle = (pfnBH)GetProcAddress(hIcmp,
            "IcmpCloseHandle");
    pIcmpSendEcho = (pfnDHDPWPipPDD)GetProcAddress(hIcmp,
            "IcmpSendEcho");
    if ((pIcmpCreateFile == 0) || (pIcmpCloseHandle == 0) || 
            (pIcmpSendEcho == 0)) {
        cerr << "Failed to get proc addr for function." << endl;
        return 4;
    }

    // Open the ping service
    HANDLE hIP = pIcmpCreateFile();
    if (hIP == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        cerr << "Unable to open ping service." << endl;
        return 5;
    }

    // Build ping packet
    char acPingBuffer[64];
    memset(acPingBuffer, '\xAA', sizeof(acPingBuffer));
    PIP_ECHO_REPLY pIpe = (PIP_ECHO_REPLY)GlobalAlloc(
            GMEM_FIXED | GMEM_ZEROINIT,
            sizeof(IP_ECHO_REPLY) + sizeof(acPingBuffer));
    if (pIpe == 0) {
        cerr << "Failed to allocate global ping packet buffer." << endl;
        return 6;
    }
    pIpe->Data = acPingBuffer;
    pIpe->DataSize = sizeof(acPingBuffer);      

    // Send the ping packet
    DWORD dwStatus = pIcmpSendEcho(hIP, *((DWORD*)phe->h_addr_list[0]), 
            acPingBuffer, sizeof(acPingBuffer), NULL, pIpe, 
            sizeof(IP_ECHO_REPLY) + sizeof(acPingBuffer), 5000);
    if (dwStatus != 0) {
        cout << "Addr: " <<
                int(LOBYTE(LOWORD(pIpe->Address))) << "." <<
                int(HIBYTE(LOWORD(pIpe->Address))) << "." <<
                int(LOBYTE(HIWORD(pIpe->Address))) << "." <<
                int(HIBYTE(HIWORD(pIpe->Address))) << ", " <<
                "RTT: " << int(pIpe->RoundTripTime) << "ms, " <<
                "TTL: " << int(pIpe->Options.Ttl) << endl;
    }
    else {
        cerr << "Error obtaining info from ping packet." << endl;
    }

    // Shut down...
    GlobalFree(pIpe);
    FreeLibrary(hIcmp);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    WSAData wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1, 1), &wsaData) != 0) {
        return 255;
    }

    int retval = doit(argc, argv);

    WSACleanup();
    return retval;
}
```

**icmpdefs.h**

```
// Structures required to use functions in ICMP.DLL

typedef struct {
    unsigned char Ttl;                         // Time To Live
    unsigned char Tos;                         // Type Of Service
    unsigned char Flags;                       // IP header flags
    unsigned char OptionsSize;                 // Size in bytes of options data
    unsigned char *OptionsData;                // Pointer to options data
} IP_OPTION_INFORMATION, * PIP_OPTION_INFORMATION;

typedef struct {
    DWORD Address;                             // Replying address
    unsigned long  Status;                     // Reply status
    unsigned long  RoundTripTime;              // RTT in milliseconds
    unsigned short DataSize;                   // Echo data size
    unsigned short Reserved;                   // Reserved for system use
    void *Data;                                // Pointer to the echo data
    IP_OPTION_INFORMATION Options;             // Reply options
} IP_ECHO_REPLY, * PIP_ECHO_REPLY;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have some kind of control over the destination host, one way you could periodically check if the host is present without using up ephemeral ports would be to send a UDP datagram, and wait for the ICMP response to tell you that the datagram was refused by the host.

You do this by creating a SOCK_DGRAM socket, binding to a local port, and calling sendto() to send to a known remote port which is not listening. You can then poll and call recvfrom() which should give an error if your host got the ICMP response back. If the host is not up then you will not get the response. You can reuse the same socket with the same port to send as many datagrams as are required periodically.

Sending ICMP echo request requires high privileges on most system, so is hard to do directly from your code.

Here is some sample code which does roughly what I describe:

```
struct sockaddr_in local_address;
struct sockaddr_in remote_address;
int sfd;
char * remote_host;
int s;
fd_set fds;
struct timeval timeout;

remote_host = argv[1];

sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);


if (sfd < 0) {
    perror("socket");
}

memset(&local_address, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
local_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
local_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
local_address.sin_port = htons(6799);

s = bind(sfd,
         (struct sockaddr*)&local_address,
         sizeof(local_address));

if (s != 0) {
    perror("bind");
    exit(1);
}

memset(&remote_address, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
remote_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
remote_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(remote_host);
remote_address.sin_port = htons(6799);

s = sendto(sfd,
           "MSG",
           3,
           0,
           (struct sockaddr*)&remote_address,
           sizeof(remote_address));

if (s != 3) {
    perror("sento");
    exit(1);
}

FD_ZERO(&fds);
FD_SET(sfd, &fds);

timeout.tv_sec = 5;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;

s = select(sfd + 1, &fds, 0, 0, &timeout);

if (s == 1) {
    char buf[512];

    printf("Got data, host is up\n");

    s = recvfrom(sfd, &buf[0], 512, 0, 0, 0);

    perror("recvfrom");
} else {
    printf("Timeout, host is down\n");
}
```

Comment: the problem is that icmp does not rely on a port, it is encapsulated within an ip datagram. So how can I solve it otherwise?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your concern. Can you explain further?

Comment: Well 6799 isn't an ICMP Echo port so I am not sure how I should expect to receive anything back

Comment: When you try and send a UDP message to a port that is unavailable, you get back an ICMP "ICMP 192.168.0.5 udp port 6799 unreachable" message. You will not get back this message if the host your are sending the packet to is missing or down. Try using a network dumping tool yourself to see this response, though the destination host must have its firewall configured to allow packets on this UDP port.

Comment: My particular device has all ports other than 502 mapped to port 80 (I'm guessing as a user convenience) so your method wouldn't work for me unfortunately. I did not discover this until I implemented what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the source of a [short DNS resolver](http://store.naszta.hu/source/dnsquery_main.cpp) in C++.

Answer (score 0):

DNS queries are not going to help you to establish whether the box is up (which is what you seem to be trying to do).

If you can run a process on the target box, you could run a heartbeat service of some sort, which would accept a TCP  connection from the monitoring app, and send an "I'm alive" message every 2.5 seconds. The inability to connect or the lack of heartbeats would tell your monitoring app that there's a problem.

Alternatively (and perhaps more straightforwardly), why not use ICMP ping?

Comment: I am connecting to this: http://www.advantechdirect.com/eMarketingPrograms/L021113P1%20Sensor/ADAM6060_page.htm and it is just a client.

Comment: @0A0D Does it respond to pings?

Comment: @0A0D So why not just periodically ping it?

Comment: I could but I was looking for a simplistic way such as a gethostbyaddr function.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only allowed a certain number of ephemeral ports, stop using ephemeral ports. Bind the source socket to a known port number before using it to attempt to connect to the other machine.

Alternatively, you don't say why you want to avoid `ping`. If it's just about doing it in code, you can generate an ICMP packet yourself and use that.

Comment: My socket object does not allow me to specify the local port.

Comment: If you're on Winsock, you can specify the local port. Just use bind().